# ScrollView in ViewPager doesn't position correctly

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-scrollview

I want to recreate this tutorial flow: [image: iOS Screenshot]

So I have the following main layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/tutorial_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="@dimen/tutorial_pairing_padding">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/left"
            style="@style/TutorialButtonOutline"
            android:layout_width="100sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:text="@string/skip"/>

        <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
            android:id="@+id/tutorial_indicator"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/right"
            style="@style/TutorialButton"
            android:layout_width="100sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:text="@string/next"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

In java, it's pretty straigtforward `Activity` based on `AppCompatActivity` which initializes `ViewPager` and sets `FragmentPagerAdapter`. The `FragmentPagerAdapter` adapter looks like this:

```
class TutorialMonitoringPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    TutorialMonitoringPageAdapter(final FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(final int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new FragmentTutorialMonitoring1();
            case 1:
                return new FragmentTutorialMonitoring2();
            case 2:
                return new FragmentTutorialMonitoring3();
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }
}
```

The `FragmentTutorialMonitoringN` classes just inflates the following layouts:

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/tutorial_pairing_padding"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/tutorial_pairing_padding">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/monit_tutor_first_title"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/child_monitoring1"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/monit_tutor_first_text"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

But when I launch the app, the topmost text is hidden behind the ActionBar and the scrolling is all weird (it "hides" behind the buttons). See it on video:

https://youtu.be/Xd6xwmGW3Qc

What am I doing wrong?

I tried:

- Removing `fillViewport` from `ScrollView`
- Removing `ScrollView` completely
- Setting fixed height to `ViewPager` (and removing `layout_height`)

And nothing changed much.

Comment: what exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: @ankitaggarwal Proper behaviour of `ScrollView` (not showing stuff out of screen)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing `layout_gravity` from `ScrollView`'s child fixes the issue.